# Exporting List column to csv from Pandas dataframe drops commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, export-to-csv

My pandas dataframe has a column with list values ("indices"):

[image]

When I export this to as `df.to_csv(fileout,  quotechar='"', encoding='ascii')`, values in the exported file drop the commas embedded in the list:

[image]

I'm using jupyter/Python 3.x
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume we create your dataframe:

```
d={'itemID':[683435088, 683435089],
   'indices':[[14,28,88,17,51,82],[82,30,37,27,2,35]]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      itemID                   indices
0  683435088  [14, 28, 88, 17, 51, 82]
1  683435089   [82, 30, 37, 27, 2, 35]
```

Now writing in csv:

```
df.to_csv('fileout.csv', quotechar='"', encoding='ascii')
```

gives what we are looking for:

[image]

*How did you create dataframe* `df`*?*